# Would hydroponically grown beans be considered kitniyot?

Tags: passover, technology, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

As I understand it, beans were included as kitniyot because they grew in the ground next to wheat.

However, if you grew the beans [hydroponically](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/can-beans-grown-hydroponically-40891.html), would they still be classified as kitniyot?

Comment: I understood that the issue was tied to the fact that they could be tried and turned into flour. If this is the case, they'd remain kitniot

Comment: They're still the same species so I don't see why we wouldn't say lo plug in the custom.

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with hydroponics, you are asking in essence 'what if I didn't grow it next to wheat?'

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The real question is do you say "ha'adamah or "she'hakol" on them.

The issue is that it is still by definition a bean. Per the OU: The Mishnah Berurah (453:6 & 464:5) cites three reasons for the minhag (a) kitnios is harvested and processed in the same manner as chametz, (b) it is ground into flour and baked just like chametz [so people may mistakenly believe that if they can eat kitnios, they can also eat chametz], (c) it may have chametz grains mixed into it [so people who eat kitnios may inadvertently be eating chametz]. The fact that it is grown hydroponically changes nothing about the potential processing of the beans.